# unique constraint check in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am enforcing a unique constraint check in JPA for userid column which is enforced for all records in the user table.

```
@Table(name = "user",
       uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = userid))
```

My requirement is that, the userid's within a particular organization needs to be unique and not across all organizations.

How do I enforce such a check?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can specify more than one field for your unique constraint, try:

```
 uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"userid", "organizationid"})}
```

By doing this, your constraint checks whether the combination of userid and organizationid is unique.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: Appreciate your insights into this?

Campus has OneToMany Buildings
Building has OneToMany Rooms

Room names needs to be unique within a campus. Would it be possible to define such a constraint on the Room entity?