# Hibernate uniqueness Fields

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, unique

I have a class called Iteraction this iteration have many fields in special i want do a validation of uniqueness for three fields together (startDate, endDate and Project), Project is a class.

I try do something like that:

@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"startDate", "endDate", "project_id"})})

But dont work, what a want say to my validation is: i can only have ONE register of iteration in database with the same startDade, endDate and project_id:

In Rails Code i can use Scope for that, but using hibernate i don't know how, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

A quick look to the documentations shows that the syntax is a bit different:

```
@Table(name="whatever", uniqueConstraints=@Unique(columnNames={"startDate","endDate", "project_id"))
```

Hope that helps.

One more answer was at [unique constraint check in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839186/unique-constraint-check-in-jpa) — check it out.